# How to add CDN with Aurelia-CLI and RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, cdn, aurelia

I am trying to add a 3rd party extension that is only available through `CDN`. How could I add them in an `Aurelia-CLI` and/or `Aurelia WebPack` project?

The library that I'm using is `DataTables` and I got it working with `Aurelia-CLI` by modifying the `aurelia.json` file by adding this:

```
{
  "name": "datatables",
  "path": "../node_modules/datatables/media",
  "main": "js/jquery.dataTables",
  "deps": ["jquery"],
  "exports": "$",
  "resources": [
    "css/jquery.dataTables.css"
  ]
},
```

Then in my ViewModel

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import dataTable from 'datatables';

export class DataTableViewModel { 
  activate() {
      //bind your data here
  }
  attached() {
      $('#example').DataTable();
  }
}
```

But the problem that I'm facing now is to add a styling extension (a [DataTables Bootstrap 4 theme](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html)).

I tried adding the `CDN` inside the `index.html` and even if that doesn't give any errors, it doesn't seem to work either.

```
<body aurelia-app="main">
  <script src="scripts/vendor-bundle.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js">
    </script>
</body>
```

I also tried adding it inside the `aurelia.json` configuration file by adding the `CDN` inside the `paths` and then using it in the `deps` but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
"paths": {
    "root": "src",
    "resources": "src/resources",
    "elements": "src/resources/elements",
    "attributes": "src/resources/attributes",
    "valueConverters": "src/resources/value-converters",
    "bindingBehaviors": "src/resources/binding-behaviors",
    "dataTablesBootstrap4": ["//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"]
  },
...
{
  "name": "datatables",
  "path": "../node_modules/datatables/media",
  "main": "js/jquery.dataTables",
  "deps": ["jquery", "dataTablesBootstrap4"],
  "exports": "$",
  "resources": [
    "css/jquery.dataTables.css"
  ]
},
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I just found this `Aurelia-CLI` [issue #313](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/313) which is probably related and might mean that there is currently no ways of importing `CDN`.

Answer (score 2):

Because bundles do not get lazily loaded and all lumped into the same bundle anyway, you can just add the CDN script into your `index.html` file to achieve the same thing. Or you can insert the script into the page where you need it on a per-need basis (kind of faking lazy loading).

Comment: Thanks Dwayne, I thought this was not possible but perhaps I didn't try it correctly. However by doing so, isn't that going in a global variable? There's no way to do like an `import` by adding them in `index.html`, is that correct?